# Call Session Value from asp.net to Flash using Action Script 3.0

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript-3

I have a login form in ASP.Net when user login he will jump on another page which consist a link of flash game.

When user click on flash game link, the flash game call the session from ASP.Net and on welcome screen show the name of the user in swf file and if he make the high score his high score save.

Next time when he login his high score will shown on screen.

The main problem is how to call the session from asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URLLoader for that in Flash ActionScript 3.0, Just create separate aspx page for retrieving session varialbe in flash. for more information check this [link](http://tush.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/actionscript-3-using-urlloader-to-send-and-load-server-variables/)

**No idea about aspx but here is the sample with PHP.**

**Actionscript 3.0**

```
var current_session_id = stage.loaderInfo.parameters.session_id; // retrieve current session id from FlashVars.

var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("your aspx page url");
var urlVariable:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_complete);


btn_submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_submit_click);
function btn_submit_click(e:Event)
{

        urlVariable.session_id = current_session_id;
        urlRequest.data = urlVariable;

        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
}

function urlLoader_complete(e:Event)
{
        trace(e.target.data.test_var); // will get session variable.
}
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php

    session_id($_REQUEST['session_id']);
    session_start();

    echo "test_var=".$_SESSION['your session varialbe'];
?>
```

Note: you need to pass current session_id along with your aspx page url. otherwise your backend aspx page generate new session id and you will not get proper session.